# refrain from unescaping special characters when receiving restcontext json?

Tags: apex, json, deserialize, restresource

I've set up an `@RestResource` class for receiving an external JSON webhook through an `@httppost` class, which is working great, but when retrieving the content of the request through `RestContext.request.requestBody.toString()`, escaped special characters within JSON strings, specifically `\"`, appear to be unescaping to `"`, which then prevents `JSON.deserialize()` from correctly parsing the string.

Example code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/rest')
global class listener {

   public class parseJSON {
       public string field;
    }

    @HttpPost
    global static void postmethod(){
        JSON.deserialize(RestContext.request.requestBody.toString(), parseJSON.class);
    }
}
```

In this example, a request body of:`{"field":"value"}` will succeed.

However, a request body of `{"field":"value \" "}`, produces the following error:

```
FATAL_ERROR System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:20]`
```

Am I approaching/understanding this correctly?

Comment: How are you hitting this endpoint? Passing the second payload in through the Developer Workbench gives me no error.

Comment: Thank you! It was in fact just a silly issue with the encoding of the request, not sending properly escaped characters in the first place, I can't believe I didn't think to check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like an issue with how you send the payload. When I send either payload to an identical endpoint, I get a successful request.

Comment: Should I be marking this answer as correct or just deleting the question entirely, given that there does not appear to be any issue on the salesforce side?

Comment: It's certainly your choice. I see no problem with leaving it, as it was well asked and included all relevant details. That way it reflects positively on your account. Having a deleted question does rather the opposite.

Comment: Well, in that case, I would much prefer to be reflected positively when possible. Thanks again!

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Cheers!